# ¿Cómo poner en SQL un TOP de un número calculado y cuando estás agrupando?

Tags: sql, sql-server, tablas

En SQL Server, imaginémonos que partimos de la siguiente tabla:

`SELECT CODART, VCUALIDAD, HCUALIDAD, UNIDADES FROM ARTICULOS`

| CODART | VCUALIDAD | HCUALIDAD | UNIDADES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 01 | 6 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 01 | 6 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 01 | 6 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 01 | 6 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 01 | 6 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 01 | 6 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 02 | 2 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 02 | 2 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 03 | 2 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 03 | 2 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 03 | 2 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 03 | 2 |

Si agrupo por las tres primeras columnas sacará tres registros.

`SELECT COUNT(CODART) AS AGRUPADOS, VCUALIDAD, HCUALIDAD, UNIDADES FROM ARTICULOS GROUP BY CODART, VCUALIDAD, HPOSCUALID, UNIDADES`

| AGRUPADOS | CODART | VCUALIDAD | HCUALIDAD | UNIDADES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 900P.0 | 100 | 01 | 6 |
| 2 | 900P.0 | 100 | 02 | 2 |
| 4 | 900P.0 | 100 | 03 | 2 |

Por último, creo una nueva columna que guarde el resultado de dividir los artículos agrupados por el campo unidades:

`SELECT COUNT(CODART) AS AGRUPADOS, (COUNT(CODART)/UNIDADES) AS UNIDADESFIN, VCUALIDAD, HCUALIDAD, UNIDADES FROM ARTICULOS GROUP BY CODART, VCUALIDAD, HPOSCUALID, UNIDADES`

| AGRUPADOS | UNIDADESFIN | CODART | VCUALIDAD | HCUALIDAD | UNIDADES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 1 | 900P.0 | 100 | 01 | 6 |
| 2 | 1 | 900P.0 | 100 | 02 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 | 900P.0 | 100 | 03 | 2 |

Esta última columna, UNIDADESFIN, la quiero emplear para sacar una cantidad concreta de registros por cada artículo, con el fin de que quede respecto a la tabla original de esta manera:

| CODART | VCUALIDAD | HCUALIDAD | UNIDADES |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 01 | 6 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 02 | 2 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 03 | 2 |
| 900P.0 | 100 | 03 | 2 |

No sé si se puede poner de alguna manera un TOP en una consulta con un GROUP BY. Pero para este caso el TOP no sería un número expreso sino calculado, UNIDADESFIN.

He intentado hacerlo con una tabla contador con tal de que me duplicara en este ejemplo el registro de 03 en HCUALIDAD, pero no da resultado pues se queda igual:

```
WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CODART, VCUALIDAD, HCUALIDAD) AS LINEA, COUNT(CODART)/UNIDADES AS UNIDADESFIN, CODART, VCUALIDAD, HCUALIDAD, UNIDADES 
    FROM ARTICULOS
    GROUP BY CODART,VCUALIDAD,HCUALIDAD,UNIDADES
    )
SELECT COUNT(CODART)/UNIDADES AS UNIDADESFIN, CODART, VCUALIDAD, HCUALIDAD, UNIDADES 
FROM ARTICULOS
LEFT JOIN CTE ON UNIDADESFIN >= CTE.LINEA
GROUP BY CODART,VCUALIDAD,HCUALIDAD,UNIDADES
```

Haciendo pruebas sin GROUP BY, este método para duplicar registros a partir de los valores de una columna sí funciona.
¿Hay alguna alternativa para sacar un determinado número de filas por agrupaciones?

Comment: no sin usar SQL dinámico y probablemente un cursor. De la forma que lo estás haciendo es la mejor alternativa

Answer (score 0):

La forma más sencilla de realizar esto es con una tabla de números o *tally table* como se le llama en inglés. Básicamente se trata de una tabla con una columna que tiene una sucesión de números enteros. Por lo general, yo uso una serie de CTEs en cascada que calculan la tabla sin necesidad de hacer ninguna lectura de disco.

Con la tabla de números, solo hacemos un JOIN desigual que regrese las filas que necesites en cada valor.

```
WITH 
E(n) AS(  --10 filas
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS( --10x10 = 100 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS( --100x100 = 10,000 filas
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(--Generamos los números
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
),
cteArticulos AS( --Hacemos el cálculo de unidadesfin
    SELECT COUNT(CODART) AS AGRUPADOS, 
            (COUNT(CODART)/UNIDADES) AS UNIDADESFIN, 
            VCUALIDAD, 
            HCUALIDAD, 
            UNIDADES 
    FROM ARTICULOS 
    GROUP BY CODART, 
             VCUALIDAD, 
             HCUALIDAD, 
             UNIDADES
)
SELECT a.*
FROM cteArticulos a
JOIN cteTally     t ON a.unidadesfin >= t.n;
```

Podríamos hacer que el código se vea más sencillo convirtiendo la tabla de números en una función que reciba como parámetro la cantidad de filas que debe regresar.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.fnTally(
    @limit  int
)
RETURNS TABLE WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
RETURN
WITH 
E(n) AS(
    SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0),(0))E(n)
),
E2(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E a, E b
),
E4(n) AS(
    SELECT a.n FROM E2 a, E2 b
),
cteTally(n) AS(
    SELECT TOP(@limit) ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) n
    FROM E4
)
SELECT n
FROM cteTally;

GO
```

Ya solo tenemos que llamar la función con la instrucción APPLY

```
WITH cteArticulos AS(
    SELECT COUNT(CODART) AS AGRUPADOS, 
            (COUNT(CODART)/UNIDADES) AS UNIDADESFIN, 
            VCUALIDAD, 
            HCUALIDAD, 
            UNIDADES 
    FROM ARTICULOS 
    GROUP BY CODART, 
             VCUALIDAD, 
             HCUALIDAD, 
             UNIDADES
)
SELECT *
FROM cteArticulos a
CROSS APPLY dbo.fnTally( UNIDADESFIN) t;
```